# How get Live value of seekBar outside of onProgressChanges?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[here im making a  number Table app with seekBar and want to show these values in ListView]

so i facing some problems

**Problem-1**: if i make "seekProg" inside onProgessChanged then, i can not access seekProg function outside.

**Problem-2**: Here i can not use ArrayAdaptor inside seekBarChangeListener [because it shows error].

So i want to get Live change value outside of seekBarChangeListener. so how can i get??

```
package com.andro.table;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        TextView textView=findViewById(R.id.textView);
        SeekBar seekBar=findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        seekBar.setMax(20);

        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }
        });

        int seekProg= seekBar.getProgress(); 
        textView.setText(""+seekProg);


        int tableValue= seekBar.getProgress();
        ListView mylistView= findViewById(R.id.myListView);
        ArrayList<String> table =new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=1;i<=20;i++) {

            int a=tableValue*i;
            table.add(tableValue+" * "+ i+ "="+a);
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,table);
        mylistView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just use the tableValue naa, you can do this i think

seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

```
       int tableValue=0;
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

      tableValue= progress;
        }
```

you can also declare the tableValue just below you declared the TextView.Hope this will help you if not please comment.